# Ramda compose throws errors with filter/map

Tags: ramda.js

I'm learning ramda by rewriting a function we have that parses numbers inside parenthesis in an array of strings. When I write this as a single compose function, both commented `filter` and `map` lines throw an error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fantasy-land/filter')`

Yet when I write them as two different compose functions, they work fine.

The match/nth compose returns `[ '123', '456', '789' ]`

When I debug, it looks like R.filter and R.map are operating on the individual characters of the strings instead of each element that R.nth is returning.

`[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]`

Not working:

```js
const extractNumbersInParenthesesFilterAndConvert = R.compose(
  R.map(Number), // errors
  R.filter(Boolean), // errors
  R.nth(1),
  R.match(/\((\d+)\)$/)
);

// Function to process an array of strings and return the extracted numbers
const extractNumbersFromStrings = R.map(extractNumbersInParenthesesFilterAndConvert);

const inputArray = [
  'Some text (123)',
  'Another string (456)',
  'No numbers here',
  'Last string (789)',
];

let result = extractNumbersFromStrings(inputArray);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Working:

```js
const extractNumbersInParentheses = R.compose(
  // R.map(Number), // errors
  // R.filter(Boolean), // errors
  R.nth(1),
  R.match(/\((\d+)\)$/)
);

const filterAndConvert = R.compose(
  R.map(Number),
  R.filter(Boolean)
);

// Function to process an array of strings and return the extracted numbers
const extractNumbersFromStrings = R.map(extractNumbersInParentheses);

const inputArray = [
  'Some text (123)',
  'Another string (456)',
  'No numbers here',
  'Last string (789)',
];

let result = extractNumbersFromStrings(inputArray);
result = filterAndConvert(result)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `R.match/R.nth` functions are being run via `R.map` on each string in the array, but `R.filter/R.map` are meant to run on the *results* of that map, yet are inside the compose so they're running on the result of each individual string regex/nth.

Throwing an `R.tap` in there to debug confirms:

```
const full = R.compose(
  R.tap(x => console.log(typeof x, x)),
  R.nth(1),
  R.match(/\((\d+)\)$/)
);
```

```
string 123
string 456
undefined undefined
string 789
```

It works as two composes because one operates on each string while the second operates on the results. Knowing this, it can be rewritten a variety of ways. Here's one:

```js
const extractCounts= R.compose(R.nth(1), R.match(/\((\d+)\)$/))
const filterAndConvert = R.compose(R.map(Number), R.filter(Boolean))
const parseNumbersFromParenthesis = R.compose(filterAndConvert, R.map(extractCounts))

console.log(parseNumbersFromParenthesis([
  'Some text (123)',
  'Another string (456)',
  'No numbers here',
  'Last string (789)',
])) // prints [ 123, 456, 789 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one function to convert a string to a number, and another to map the array, convert the strings to numbers, and then filter out `NaN` values.

Don't use `Boolean` because they would also remove 0 values. Use `Math.isNaN()` instead.

```js
const { compose, match, last, map, reject } = R;

const extractNumbersInParentheses = compose(
  Number, // convert to number
  last, // take the last match (the capture group)
  match(/\((\d+)\)$/) // extract number
);

// Function to process an array of strings and return the extracted numbers
const extractNumbersFromStrings = compose(
  reject(Number.isNaN), // remove NaN items
  map(extractNumbersInParentheses)
);

const inputArray = ['Some text (123)', 'Another string (456)',  'No numbers here', 'Last string (789)'];

const result = extractNumbersFromStrings(inputArray);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.js"></script>
```